# x/mobile: Launch a android application with given package name [String] in go

Tags: go, gomobile

Following is the function written in go:

```
func LaunchApplication(packageName string) {
 Query :
 how can I execute application with given packageName

}
```

Generated the java binding [.aar] using gomobile.
I want to include .aar generated in my android application and call LaunchApplication("com.package.name") from java layer to native go layer and go layer should run the application.

In java application, following is the way to run apk using package name:

```
Process process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("am start -n com.package.name/com.package.name.ActivityName");
```

I tried the same in go using:
**os.exec() function but it is giving error that "am not found in the $PATH"**

Is there is any other way to do that ?

Answer (score 0):

In android, you should specify the path "/system/bin/"(/system/bin/am). Please make sure there are "am" in this path.